# How to get data which is not present in IN clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, in-clause

I tried below query on **'email'**  table

```
SELECT email_id,count(*) as count FROM email 
where  email_id in ('a@a.com','b@b.com','c@c.com') group by email_id
```

**Result**

```
email_id   count

a@a.com     3

c@c.com     2
```

but I want result like with below sequence

```
email_id     count

a@a.com       3

b@b.com       0

c@c.com       2
```

For your information  b@b.com not present in email table

Comment: probably a `left join` with an `ifnull()`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Can you please provide me query or example in your way.It will help me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Schema

```
create table users
(   userId int auto_increment primary key,
    userName varchar(100) not null,
    emailAddr varchar(200) not null
);

create table emails
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    userId int not null
-- etc
);

insert users(userName,emailAddr) values ('Sally','sally10@gmail.com'),('Henry','h@h.com'),('JT','abcde@xxx.org');

insert emails(userId) values (1),(1),(1),(3),(3);
```

### Query

```
select u.userId,u.emailAddr,count(e.id) as theCount
from users u
left join emails e
on e.userId=u.userId
group by u.userId,u.emailAddr
+--------+-------------------+----------+
| userId | emailAddr         | theCount |
+--------+-------------------+----------+
|      1 | sally10@gmail.com |        3 |
|      2 | h@h.com           |        0 |
|      3 | abcde@xxx.org     |        2 |
+--------+-------------------+----------+
```

`Left join` picks up missing emails existences so to speak.

Comment: your answer give me  clue to solve my problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT e1.email_id, COUNT(e2.email_id) AS count 
FROM (SELECT 'a@a.com' AS email_id 
      UNION 
      SELECT 'b@b.com'
      UNION
      SELECT 'c@c.com'
 ) AS e1
LEFT JOIN email AS e2 ON e1.email_id = e2.email_id
GROUP BY e1.email_id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0de98/4)

Comment: but I have lots of email_ids in IN clause then how can I manage with above query in context of UNION with each email_id. It's makes big query

Comment: @Harshal Instead of placing the emails in a comma separated list consumed by the `IN` operator, you can place them in the in-line table. Otherwise you have to create a temp or lookup table containing all the emails.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this probably:

```
SELECT t.email_id,count(e.email_id) as count 
FROM 
(
select 'a@a.com' as email_id union all
select 'b@b.com' union all
select 'c@c.com'
) t
left join email e on t.email_id = e.email_id
group by t.email_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT 'a@a.com' as email_id,count(1)  as `count` FROM email where email_id='a@a.com'
union
SELECT 'b@b.com' as email_id,count(1) as `count`  FROM email where email_id='b@b.com'
union
SELECT 'c@c.com' as email_id,count(1) as `count`  FROM email where email_id='c@c.com'
```